# I want to close the popup for Shopee site https://shopee.vn/ in selenium by clicking the X button

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, shopee

[I would like to use selinium to click the X button; but it does not work what ever try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BRZh.jpg)

I used the following code to executed the request but it didn't work
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"shopee-popup__close-btn")]))).click()